# Does the Firebase Spark (free) plan work on a per project basis?

Tags: firebase

I use Firebase's Spark (free) plan.

Are the limitations that are given to (database simultaneous connections, database storage, etc.) are project based or user based.

For example I have two projects:

1. The first project have (an android app and an iOS app) and have 80 database simultaneous connections.
2. The second project has only an android app with 50 database simultaneous connections.

Am I in this case exceeding the limitation (user based) or not (project based)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

All limits and pricing indicated on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) apply to each separate project.

So in your example neither project would be exceeding the limits of its free plan.